# Can you use a domain name while transferring it

Tags: domain-name

I am transferring a domain name from one hosting company to another. The new hosting site has a website ready to use. How can I use the domain name now while it’s being moved. They say it could take up to 10 days ( I have never had to wait that long before.). I know there is a way but can’t remember.

Comment: You are not telling the domain nor even the TLD, and the answer will depend on this information. In general, like in gTLD, a transfer is done without any technical changes at the same time, it is only an **administrative** change to move sponsorship of the domain from registrar A to registrar B. In gTLD a transfer can be delayed for up to 5 days after which the regsitry auto-acknowledge it. Note however that if you are using old registrar DNS service at the same time, transferring out of it may break DNS resolution, based on what kind of service you subscribed with it. In short,too few details

Answer (score 0):

The domain name will resolve to the current DNS entry until it is updated after being moved to the new host. In other words, you don’t need to do anything.

If you want to experiment with the new host before the DNS entry has been updated then use the URL usually provided by the new hosting service for that purpose.

Comment: So if I do a forward now on the old account to forward the domain to a new website on a different hosting - it will work until the domain is fully transferred to the new account.

Comment: Correct. Just be sure to the new hosting company is aware of the domain name(s) you are planning to transfer. They will ensure that your domain names point to the correct endpoint so that once the transfer is complete your site will render as it does today. Users never will know that they're hitting a newly hosted site as long as you've copied all site content from your existing company's hosting platform to the new company's hosting platform.